# Vanilla JS resizing animation works in every browser but Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, svg, firefox, frontend

I have a div wrapped around an inline SVG in my HTML that has a movement and resizing animation in JS triggered by the user scrolling down, like so:

*HTML:*

```
<div id="pepper-logo" onclick="navClick()" onmouseover="logoOpacity(this)" onmouseout="logoNormal(this)">
  <svg>
     ...
  </svg>
</div>
```

*JS Code:*

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(e) {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10) {
    logoText.style.opacity='0';
    logo.style.left="60px";
    logo.style.top="-10px";
    logo.style.opacity="0.65";
    logoSVG.style.width="90";
    logoSVG.style.height="130";
    logo.style.zIndex='2';
    logoPath.style.fill="#62b564";
  }
});
```

In every browser I've tried it on (Chrome, Edge, FF, Safari Mobile), this is triggered properly and does the movement animation to the left edge, however for whatever reason Firefox doesn't do the width and height resizing. I've tried searching for incompatibilities with these specific actions and can't find anything, nor does it make sense to me that FF would just be missing these style options and nothing else.

After 2 days of trying I'm out of ideas, and it's basically the only thing left for me to fix before the site launches. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: JSfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/h37pfwcs/3/
SOLVED: Missing units in style code.

Comment: please use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to create a runnable but minimal testcase. There's so little in the code you've posted it's impossible to tell what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Like the above comment said, and also you said "*every browser except Firefox*", maybe check if some of your properties are not supported for Firefox in [https://caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com)

Comment: Added jsfiddle example

Comment: @Lacomus Instead of a jsfiddle, really please use the runnable snippet functionality built into Stackoverflow. There is no reason to link out for this code. Just [edit] your post, and click the little document with `<>` inside of it.

Comment: Missing units on logoSVG.style.width and logoSVG.style.height - that's a Chrome bug you've found. Units are mandatory in CSS per w3c

Comment: As a follow-up to that: don't set `style` properties, use the `.classList` property to add or remove classes to your elements, so that your CSS can live in your CSS file(s), with all the CSS-specific linting and error-catching that your IDE/editor will do for you.

Comment: Thank you Robert that was it! Can't believe I overlooked that for so long, guess every other browser could figure it out.

Comment: Every other browser is simply wrong. Allowing no units means that calc doesn't work properly.